# SQL join is returning all instances where a join is found rather than joining assigned

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have 3 tables: OpportunityContact, TaskContact, and Tasks.

- OpportunityContact is a join table for Opportunities and Contacts
- TaskContact is a join table for Tasks and Contacts.
- Task contains a status and id.

  - status field can be in 'In Progress', 'In Review', or 'Completed'

Relationships
An Opportunity has many Tasks. A Contact can be assigned to many Tasks. An Opportuntiy has many Contacts.

Relevant Tables

```
task:
-----
id
status
opportunity_id

task_contact
-----
task_id
contact_id

opportunity_contact
-----
opportunity_id
contact_id
```

Problem:
Given a contact_id I want to determine the Tasks this Contact is assigned too AND count the statuses of each Task they are assigned to.

Example:

- There are 2 Opportunities (id = 1 and id = 2)
- Contact with id = 1 is assigned to both Opportunities.
- Contact with id = 1 is assigned to only 1 Task with id = 1. The Task belongs to Opportunity where id = 1
- There are 25 Tasks all belonging to Opportunity with id = 1 all with a status of 'In Progress'
- There are 24 Tasks all belonging to Opportunity with id = 2 all with a status of 'In Progress'

I would like my SQL result to produce the following result.

```
| contact_id | opportunity_id | total_tasks_count | tasks_in_progress_count | tasks_in_review_count |tasks_completed_count |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 1              | 1                  | 1                       | 0                     |0                    |
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 2              | 0                  | 0                       | 0                     |0                    |
```

The SQL I've tried:

```
SELECT  distinct
  ocr.contact_id,
  ocr.opportunity_id,
  task.status,
  sum(case when task.status is NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) total_tasks_count, 
  sum(case when task.status = 'In Progress' then 1 else 0 end) tasks_in_progress_count, 
  sum(case when task.status = 'In Review' then 1 else 0 end) tasks_in_review_count, 
  sum(case when task.status = 'Completed' then 1 else 0 end) tasks_completed_count
FROM opportunity_contact ocr 
LEFT JOIN task ON ocr.opportunity_id = task.opportunity_id 
LEFT JOIN task_contact tc ON task.id = tc.task_id 
WHERE
  ocr.contact_id = '1'
GROUP BY 
  ocr.opportunity_id,
  task.status,
  ocr.contact_id;
```

The result I get:

```
| contact_id | opportunity_id | total_tasks_count | tasks_in_progress_count | tasks_in_review_count |tasks_completed_count |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 1              | 25                | 25                       | 0                     |0                    |
| --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1          | 2              | 24                | 24                       | 0                     |0                    |
```

Why is my query counting all 25 Tasks when Contact with id = 1 is only assigned to 1 Task?!? How can I get it to include the other opportunity to which the same contact has no assigned tasks?

Please and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to `opportunity_contact` in your query, but it is not part of the problem statement.  The contact is in the `task_contact` table, so that should be sufficient for filtering:

```
SELECT ocr.contact_id, task.task_id,
       count(task.status) as total_tasks_count, 
       sum( (task.status = 'In Progress')::int)  as tasks_in_progress_count, 
       sum( (task.status = 'In Review')::int) as tasks_in_review_count, 
       sum( (task.status = 'Completed')::int as tasks_completed_count
FROM task JOIN
     task_contact tc
     ON task.id = tc.task_id 
WHERE tc.contact_id = '1'
GROUP BY ocr.contact_id, task.id;
```

Comment: That's because I want to pull all the Opportunities to which they are assigned and then sum/count those task statuses. However, when they are assigned to an Opportunity but not assigned to any tasks, i still want to sum those tasks as 0.